# Deriving log-likelihood for summation of binomial and poisson random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a general model: $Y_t = g(Y_{t-1})+U_t$ where if we condition on $Y_{t-1}$, then $g(Y_{t-1})$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $Y_{t-1}$ and $\alpha$ and $U_t$ is a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ and $g(Y_{t-1})$ and $U_t$ are independent of each other. I am asked to derive the log-likelihood (conditional on $Y_1$) for the MLE estimation of $\alpha$ and $\lambda$.

The following is my working so far:

First I derive the pmf of $Y_t$ (conditional on $Y_{t-1}$). We have:

\begin{align*}P(Y_t=y|Y_{t-1}) 
& = \sum_{j=0}^{\min(y,Y_{t-1})} P(g(Y_{t-1})=j, U_t=y-j) \\
& = \sum_{j=0}^{\min(y,Y_{t-1})} \binom{Y_{t-1}}{j} \alpha^j (1-\alpha)^{Y_{t-1}-j} \cdot \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{y-j}}{(y-j)!} \ \ \text{Due to the assumed independence}
 \end{align*}

Now I am unsure how to derive the (log)-likelihood as I don't really know how to deal with the summation. Any help would be appreciated.